# Success message not showing after deleting the object in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, postman

I have a **DestroyAPIView** in which I am using the **perform_delete** function to delete an instance. However, I want to send a success message with 200 status. I tried, but in the postman I am getting blank with 204 status. How can I acheive this??

My view:

```
class UpdateOrderView(UpdateAPIView,DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    #queryset = Order.objects.prefetch_related('order_items').all()
    #value = self.kwargs['pk']
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    print(queryset)
    serializer_class = OrderUpdateSerializer

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        if instance.delete():
            return Response({
                "message":"Order deleted successfully"
            },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            pass
```

**The instance is deleted, I have checked the db, but I am not getting success message.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`destroy`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/mixins.py#L89) method instead.

```
class UpdateOrderView(UpdateAPIView,DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderUpdateSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response({
            "message":"Order deleted successfully"
        },
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete()
```

Comment: Hello @Abdul , thanks it worked. So just last question. So perform_destory is used only for case like this?? I am not really sure when to use destroy and when to use perform_destroy. Can you explain??

Comment: @Django-Rocks I think you should  override `destroy` when you want to change the API response(Like in this case) and use `perform_destroy` when you want much granular check over the instance deletion. For [example](https://github.com/iodide-project/iodide/blob/master/server/notebooks/api_views.py#L126).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to know how many years have you been working on django to get such knowlegde and reputations of 5k+.. I am just starting not even a year, 10 months.